# Apply a style on element A if element B contains a certain class

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to check the class of an element, see if it exists, and then apply the style for another class?

Example pseudo code:

```js
if (.myClass .myBlock == true) { 
  .otherClass { 
    display:none 
  }
}
```

Comment: nope. It is not possible

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in this context. But you can achieve a similar result with the cascading nature of CSS.

**Apply a class to the body of your website:**

```
.another-class {
    display: none; // hides .another-class by default
}

body.special-class {
    .another-class {
        display: block; // shows if the body contains .special-class
    }
}
```

Since the specificity of the generated output is higher at the second rule, the elements with `.another-class` will be visible.

**Give the following row a class**

Utilising the `+` selector enables us to display the row `after` the mentioned class. This way we can style dropdowns popups, given we have the following HTML:

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup:hover {
  display: block;
}

.container:hover + .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Hover me!</div>
<div class="popup">This is a popup!</div>
```

I'm afraid that's all that is possible with CSS.